# Angular: dynamic value issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show different data from a large data object based on selections made in view via a select box.  I am populating the data like this

```
$scope.displayData = $scope.dataObj[$scope.selectedType][$scope.networkType];
```

And I have ng-model on my select options.

```
<select ng-model="networkType">
    <option value="networkOne">One</option>
    <option value="networkTwo">Two</option>
    <option value="networkThree">Three</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedType">
    <option value="typeOne">One</option>
    <option value="typeTwo">Two</option>
    <option value="typeThree">Three</option>
</select>
```

I initialize both of these variables

```
    $scope.selectedType = 'individual';
    $scope.networkType = 'inNetwork';
```

And the $scope.displayData is initially correct.  However when I change the drop downs, the displayData does not change its values to access the new data. I am not sure what step I am missing here.

Comment: i think you're missing lots of things here. Where is your ng-change=() method?

Comment: You are setting the value of `displayData` only once ... this is no *live view*. You need to update the value when updating the dropdowns. See `ng-change` docs

Comment: I wasn't aware I would need one.  The values of selectedType and networkType get updated as soon as they are changed in the select drop down, so I thought that those values in the dynamic variable would change also?

Comment: @mls3590712 those variables are only evaluated at the time of execution. Either need to watch for changes or use dom events to make adjustments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should update the display data using `ng-change` event.

Add a update function in your controller

```
$scope.updateDisplay = function() {
    $scope.displayData = $scope.dataObj[$scope.selectedType][$scope.networkType];
};
```

Add `ng-change` for your `<select>` element

```
<select ng-model="networkType" ng-change="updateDisplay()">
    <option value="networkOne">One</option>
    <option value="networkTwo">Two</option>
    <option value="networkThree">Three</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedType" ng-change="updateDisplay()">
    <option value="typeOne">One</option>
    <option value="typeTwo">Two</option>
    <option value="typeThree">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is a clear and straight forward way of solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Or do it with $scope.$watch.

The $scope.watch() function creates a watch of some variable. When you register a watch you pass two functions as parameters to the $watch() function:

- A value function
- A listener function

The first function is the value function and the second function is the listener function.

The value function should return the value which is being watched. AngularJS can then check the value returned against the value the watch function returned the last time. That way AngularJS can determine if the value has changed.

In my example, we are setting up a watch on both networkType and selectedType models. And instead of it being a funtion we simply put the $scope model name.

```
$scope.$watch('[networkType,selectedType]', function(newValues, oldValues) {
    $scope.displayData = $scope.dataObj[newValues.selectedType][newValues.networkType];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your controller

```
$scope.onChnage = function () {
        $scope.displayData = $scope.dataObj[$scope.selectedType][$scope.networkType];
}
```

Html

```
<select ng-model="networkType" ng-change="onChnage ()">
    <option value="networkOne">One</option>
    <option value="networkTwo">Two</option>
    <option value="networkThree">Three</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="selectedType" ng-change="onChnage ()">
    <option value="typeOne">One</option>
    <option value="typeTwo">Two</option>
    <option value="typeThree">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside $watch and ng-change, if you just want to display the data in displayData variable, another option is to convert it to a function display():

```
$scope.display = function () {
    return $scope.dataObj[$scope.selectedType][$scope.networkType];
};
```

and in the view:

```
{{display()}}
```

this function will be called again whenever selectedType or networkType change

Comment: I really like this solution for its elegance, however I do need to have it saved in a variable, so I will have to take one of the other options.